# Dots (coordinates) on a static map

Tags: python, django, database, maps

I would like to display a dots on the static map ( taken from database )
result would look something like:

[image]

there are latitude and longtitude data in my database for each object that i would like to display.

The question is: is this only possible by using some kind of google API? or this could be done in some other way?
Maybe somebody seen something similar and would give me a hint where to start?

Update:

I've gone so far that the only thing is to convert html object to js array.
Any idea how to?
Html::

```
{% for c in object_list %}
```

JS::

```
var flights = {% for c in object_list %} <<--- convert to js..
```

Views.py :

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .serializers import Flightserializer
from .models import Flights




class FlightViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Flights.objects.all().order_by('aircraft')
    serializer_class = Flightserializer

class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Flights
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

JS:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
           var locations = [
  ["LOCATION_1", 58.008759, -0.410570],
  ["LOCATION_2", 59.0059, -0.4105],
]; # here i need to insert data from django model..
            var map = L.map('map',{
        keyboard: false,
        dragging: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        boxZoom: false,
        doubleClickZoom: false,
        scrollWheelZoom: false,
        tap: false,
        touchZoom: false,
        center: [55.545454, -22.525252],
        zoom: 7,
        minZoom: 7,
        maxZoom: 0
    });
                var tileLayer = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors' }).addTo(map);
                for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new L.marker([locations[i][1], locations[i][2]])
    .bindPopup(locations[i][0])
    .addTo(map);
}
                
    
                
                
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help you: https://leafletjs.com/

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();
```

Comment: thank you for this.

Any idea how to add multiple markers using something that i'm using for html?
I've updated question

Comment: You can declare multiple Markers, I will edit the code

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript you can do something like this :

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors' }).addTo(map);

for(let obj of object_list) {
    L.marker([obj .coordinates.x, obj .coordinates.y]).addTo(map) 
.bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup. Easily customizable.') .openPopup();
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. No markers on the map.

Comment: Do you have some errors on the console developer

Comment: No, maybe because i use django then i have to do it in the different way? Seen somewhere that views.py should be modified.

Comment: of course you have to find a way to send your object_list which seems to be the list of the items you want to place on the map to you javascript then you can display it on the map. Maybe create an url in your django projet witch return object_list as json then get it in your javascipt by fetching the url

Comment: Ok thanks for advice will try and will come back with updates

Comment: Still trying to figure out how to convert this django model data into <script> no luck so far..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you iDz iDz for guiding me through this.
Finally sorted.
Right approach was in html file:

```
var locations_json = "{{ data|safe }}";
```

in views.py :

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['data'] = [
            {
                'aircraft': obj.aircraft,
                'latitude': obj.latitude,
                'longtitude': obj.longtitude
            }
            for obj in Flights.objects.all()
        ]

        return context
```